# Azure DevOps Extension Development without Client Library

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to write an Extension for Azure DevOps 2019 Server which will list the available dashboards and allow them to be deleted.

I have already created an extension and have used the REST Client to get work items.  As per here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/rest-clients?view=azure-devops

However it appears that there is no REST Client for the API Dashboard functions that I need to use.  How can I make calls to the API from within an Extension when there is no REST Client available?  I can't find an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azure-devops-node-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api) that have [methods](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/master/samples/dashboard.ts) to interact with the dashboards.

In addition, you can use the [Dashboard Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and make Http request like every rest api call, you can read [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html) "5 Ways to Make HTTP Requests in Node.js".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Shouldn't I be doing this with the azure-devops-extension-api?

https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk - The SDK with the easy to use client libraries but doesn't have one for Dashboards

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api - For developing NodeJS calls to DevOps, can also be called from an Extension

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api - This seems to be a new API which has calls to all the services

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk - Seems like it's just for UI related calls, doesnt actually call the API methods?

Comment: Look like you also can use `azure-devops-extension-api`. the `sdk` I think it's for develop the extension but not to interact with all azure devops.

Comment: Yes, it seems like azure-devops-extension-api is going to replace vss-web-extension-sdk.  The new one has all the Dashboard methods I need.  But there doesn't seem to be any documentation or examples on how to use it so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: you shouldn't really give an option to delete dashboard from an extension.  You can just remove the dashboard from AzDo.  I'm not sure I understand your scenario.